# How can I make an integer from list of integers?

Tags: python, for-loop

How can I make an integer from a list of integers? For example :from lst = [1, 2, 3] make a = 123?
I tried that:

```
for i in lst:
    print(i, end = '')
```

but if I need don't print, but just to have this number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use `map` to convert element in list to string
- use `str.join` to concat the element in the list

**Ex:**

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print("".join(map(str, lst)))
```

If you need `int` object

Use:

```
print(int("".join(map(str, lst))))
```

Comment: And then convert the result to an `int`

Comment: I can't help but think this is inefficient. You're converting `int` -> `str` -> `int` here. I think that's twice the number of calculations you really need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` (`functools.reduce` in Python3):

```
a = reduce( lambda x,y: 10*x + y, lst)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sum` with a generator expression:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
n = len(lst)
res = sum(val * 10**(n-idx) for idx, val in enumerate(lst, 1))
```

This is, in effect, a more explicit representation of what `int('123')` should do internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.join` method to create a string and convert it to `int` like this:

`a = int(''.join(str(x) for x in lst))`

Cheers.